# More efficient way to write a TOP 1 * query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Below is an example of a query which I think is hindering my overall performance of my stored procedure (this operation is done several times in a loop). The temporary table #PROBLEMS_RELATED_REF_FINAL is a result of a few full outer joins and is without a primary key (because as you can see by my where clause, some of the would-be primary key columns, are null). I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to get the top record where all of the conditions are met (given that there is no primary key). #PROBLEMS_RELATED_REF_FINAL will generally have about 50-1000 records.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *, NULL AS [SUBTRACTION], NULL AS [END_COUNTER]  
FROM #PROBLEMS_RELATED_REF_FINAL 
WHERE [ST_1] IS NOT NULL 
AND [ST_2] IS NOT NULL 
AND [ST_3] IS NOT NULL 
AND [ST_4] IS NOT NULL
```

The table create for #PROBLEMS_RELATED_REF_FINAL looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #PROBLEMS_RELATED_REF_FINAL (
[ST_1] CHAR(2) NULL,
[PUMA_1] CHAR(5) NULL,
[ZCTA_1] CHAR(5) NULL,
[X-XX_1] INT NULL,
[PUMA_PROBLEMS_1] CHAR(1) NULL,
[NEEDED_PUMA_GROWTH_1] INT NULL,
[COUNTER_1] INT NULL,
[ST_2] CHAR(2) NULL,
[PUMA_2] CHAR(5) NULL,
[ZCTA_2] CHAR(5) NULL,
[X-XX_2] INT NULL,
[PUMA_PROBLEMS_2] CHAR(1) NULL,
[NEEDED_PUMA_GROWTH_2] INT NULL,
[COUNTER_2] INT NULL,
[ST_3] CHAR(2) NULL,
[PUMA_3] CHAR(5) NULL,
[ZCTA_3] CHAR(5) NULL,
[X-XX_3] INT NULL,
[PUMA_PROBLEMS_3] CHAR(1) NULL,
[NEEDED_PUMA_GROWTH_3] INT NULL,
[COUNTER_3] INT NULL,
[ST_4] CHAR(2) NULL,
[PUMA_4] CHAR(5) NULL,
[ZCTA_4] CHAR(5) NULL,
[X-XX_4] INT NULL,
[PUMA_PROBLEMS_4] CHAR(1) NULL,
[NEEDED_PUMA_GROWTH_4] INT NULL,
[COUNTER_4] INT NULL,
[ST_5] CHAR(2) NULL,
[PUMA_5] CHAR(5) NULL,
[ZCTA_5] CHAR(5) NULL,
[X-XX_5] INT NULL,
[PUMA_PROBLEMS_5] CHAR(1) NULL,
[NEEDED_PUMA_GROWTH_5] INT NULL,
[COUNTER_5] INT NULL,
[ST_6] CHAR(2) NULL,
[PUMA_6] CHAR(5) NULL,
[ZCTA_6] CHAR(5) NULL,
[X-XX_6] INT NULL,
[PUMA_PROBLEMS_6] CHAR(1) NULL,
[NEEDED_PUMA_GROWTH_6] INT NULL,
[COUNTER_6] INT NULL,
[ST_7] CHAR(2) NULL,
[PUMA_7] CHAR(5) NULL,
[ZCTA_7] CHAR(5) NULL,
[X-XX_7] INT NULL,
[PUMA_PROBLEMS_7] CHAR(1) NULL,
[NEEDED_PUMA_GROWTH_7] INT NULL,
[COUNTER_7] INT NULL,
[ST_8] CHAR(2) NULL,
[PUMA_8] CHAR(5) NULL,
[ZCTA_8] CHAR(5) NULL,
[X-XX_8] INT NULL,
[PUMA_PROBLEMS_8] CHAR(1) NULL,
[NEEDED_PUMA_GROWTH_8] INT NULL,
[COUNTER_8] INT NULL,
[ST_9] CHAR(2) NULL,
[PUMA_9] CHAR(5) NULL,
[ZCTA_9] CHAR(5) NULL,
[X-XX_9] INT NULL,
[PUMA_PROBLEMS_9] CHAR(1) NULL,
[NEEDED_PUMA_GROWTH_9] INT NULL,
[COUNTER_9] INT NULL,
[ST_10] CHAR(2) NULL,
[PUMA_10] CHAR(5) NULL,
[ZCTA_10] CHAR(5) NULL,
[X-XX_10] INT NULL,
[PUMA_PROBLEMS_10] CHAR(1) NULL,
[NEEDED_PUMA_GROWTH_10] INT NULL,
[COUNTER_10] INT NULL)
ON [PRIMARY]
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem isn't that this query is inefficient, it is the calling this several times in a loop. Loops are horribly inefficient. Also, you have a select top 1 but there is no order by so you can't be certain which row you will get back.

Comment: do it once, not once per loop

Comment: Any indexes on the temp table?

Comment: @SeanLange What's a more efficient way to do what a loop does? I'm looping through a table and using different declared variables every iteration

Comment: @Used_By_Already problem is I need to do it once per loop because the next iteration, the values outputted by the top 1 * query are completely different

Comment: @barrypicker no indexes on the temp table, which I'm assuming is the biggest problem. But it is impossible to because the primary key columns (on this temp table at least) are sometimes null

Comment: If `top 1` query tipically returns only a handful of rows [filtered indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) might improve performance.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović: Pray explain when a `TOP 1 *` query would return more than 1 row, nevermind a handful.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Funny re-reading my sentence, well English language is obviously not my strength. `TOP 1 *` was just a reference to OP's query, not that it could possibly return more than one row. What I ment was that filtered index will be great improvement if number of rows complying to condition is fairly low.

Comment: That depends on what your loop actually does but 99.9999% of the time a loop/cursor can be replaced by a single set statement. It requires a mental shift in how you think about data. You have to think about what you want to do to a column instead of a row.

Comment: @ultimate8 - why don't you try adding an index on columns `ST1` - `ST4`?

Comment: It'll be more productive if you just post your loop here. `SELECT TOP 1` is likely NOT the problem. It's the loop!

Comment: @ZoffDino I would post it but it's right around 1000 lines of code. It loops through those 1000 lines of code several hundred times for each row (select top 1 * is used once per iteration) and then there is an outer loop which makes each row go through, on average, about 5 iterations (it depends though because if it finishes in 3 iterations, it stops there and if it completes in 10 iterations, it stops there).

Comment: @chuex The problem is the values in `ST1`-`ST4` are sometimes NULL and other rows have the same `ST1`-`ST4` values. The primary key would be `ST1`,`PUMA1`,`ZCTA1`,`ST2`,`PUMA2`,`ZCTA2` etc.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović Is a filtered index the same thing as a non-clustered index?

Comment: It is non-clustered, but main feature is rapid response because it is just a list of rows satisfying a condition. And you do not need to change the query in any way. Optimizer will use the index if the query uses the same predicate as index.

Comment: @ultimate8 - without seeing more of the loop, it's difficult to understand what you are trying to do. From what you have shown here, it is irrelevant that some of the columns `ST1` - `ST4` are NULL. An index on those columns will speed up the SELECT statement above.

Comment: @chuex I assumed you were talking a clustered index, not a non-clustered index. I will try putting a non-clustered index on those columns and see where that leaves me. Should I include every column besides the columns I am placing the index on?

Comment: I would try both clustered and non-clustered to see what works better. Don't include all columns, just the ones in the WHERE clause.